# Storing Auth0 user object in React Context in nextjs Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to store Auth0 ([Auth0](https://auth0.com/)) user object returned by useUser inside react context API.
Here's my userContext.tsx, the goal is to be able to access the object inside user globally in my app:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { useUser, UserProfile } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";

type UserContextType = {
  user: UserProfile | undefined;
  error: Error | undefined;
  isLoading: boolean;
};

const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, error, isLoading }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUserContext = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

and my _app.tsx below:

```
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { UserProvider } from "@src/components/common/userContext";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: You forgot to wrap your app in <UserProvider>
```

While I obviously did wrap my app with

Comment: Does Auth0 providers <UserProvider>? Can you `import {UserProvider} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client"

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but do i have to call ```const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser()``` in every file?

Comment: If it does has `UserProvider`, you must render it at the place of your UserContext. About your question about calling `useUser`, You can call it where you need. For example, If you need the user name in the <NavBar> component, you can call it there.

Comment: I want to store it somewhere using react context and access it globally. Why I want to do this is because calling useUser() everytime fetches the user data from Auth0 server which slows down the application. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I got it, writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you need to call auth0's `useUser` once and store the data then read from your store.

First of all we need to wrap the component that calls `useUser` by `UserProvider` to be able to read from it using `useContext` hook.

```js
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { MyUserProvider } from "@src/components/common/userContext";
import { UserProvider } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <MyUserProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MyUserProvider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Then we can call `useUser` and pass it to our context:

```js
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { useUser, UserProfile } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";

type UserContextType = {
  user: UserProfile | undefined;
  error: Error | undefined;
  isLoading: boolean;
};

const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export const MyUserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, error, isLoading }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUserContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);

  if (context === null /* the initial value */) {
    throw new Error("You probably forgot to wrap your app in <MyUserProvider>")
  }

  return context;
}
```

Comment: Works like magic! You just saved me hours